# Avoid compiler optimization while reading memory

Tags: c

I want to check an ECC error in a cell of RAM memory.

In order to check ECC errors, I must read or write this memory. So I have chosen to read the memory's value, but the compiler clean this line because I don't use it in rest of my code.

Is there any way to avoid the optimization without modifying the compiler options.

Find below the sequences:

```
 1. Clear flags
 2. Read memory <==> Rt_value = (unsigned short *) Address
 3. Check flags
```

Note: I use GHS compiler.

Comment: Mark it volatile.

Comment: @Joe `volatile` doesn't guarantee that. Compiler may still remove it, if value isn't used.

Comment: Use inline assembly, but even then, it is not guaranteed that your data is written to memory instantly, because it might be buffered in a (write-back)-cache

Comment: Volatile alone doesn't prevent code from be optimized away, though it could work for a specific compiler. The simplest answer is probably to just use it in an innocuous way. Assign it to a global variable, write it to /dev/null, etc.

Comment: @user694733: That's not true unless it is an automatic variable without pointer taken (which we safely can exclude here). Please provide a reference to where the standard allows it. Don't forget to look at the corresponding defect report.

Comment: @Gene: see above ^

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], read [ask] and follow the advice.

Comment: I solved the problem by saving the content in a local variable, then set the memory to the content of the local variable. I don't want  that because this operation requires Read-Write access. Is that a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

Using volatile keyword might help.

http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359124222941.htm

Above article will help you understand use of volatile.